# Select all divs with class from var

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to select all divs with class="test" from a variable and put them into another div.

```
var all = xmlhttp.responseText;
var x = $(all > '.test');    <-- how to write correctly ?
$('.anotherdiv').prepend(x);
```

Comment: What `all` string looks like? Are DIVs targeted children or wrapping elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('<div />', {html : all}).find('.test').prependTo('.anotherdiv');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
var x = $(all).filter('div.test');
```

Or using [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var x = $(all).find('div.test');
```

Now it depends value of your string `all`

Comment: @Jess `x` will be a jQuery object containing set of matched elements. In fact OP needs to use filter() or find(), it depends what is `all` string looks like